# Locating text and performing operation based on its existence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to learn jQuery, but it's coming slowly as I really don't know any JavaScript.

My site is in VB.NET and I'm putting jQuery code on both my actual `.ascx` `UserControl` and in a separate file (something like `myscripts.js`). This is because I'm using webforms as I still don't know MVC well enough to implement it, so I have to get the clientID's on the page.

What I would like to do is the following:

1. Grab text from a textbox and make it all lowercase
2. Get the username from the login info. I've done this like so on my actual page:

   ```
   var userName = "<%=Split(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToLowerInvariant, '|')%>";
   ```
3. Check to see if the username is in the text. If it IS in the text, I want to set a variable to "false", othewise to true.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am completely ignorant of the ASP.NET side of it, but as far as jQuery and Javascript....

To get the value of a text field, you use the jQuery function [`val()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val):

```
var value = $('#mytextbox').val();
```

To turn a string to lower case, you use the string method [`toLowerCase()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toLowerCase.asp):

```
var value = $('#mytextbox').val().toLowerCase();
```

Since `val()` returns a string we can throw that at the end.

To check if a string is within another string, you use the string method [`indexOf()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp):

```
var needle = 'Hello';
var haystack = 'Hello World';
var match = haystack.indexOf(needle); // -1 if no matches, 0 in this case
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var userName = "username as it comes out of your web app";

// stuff happens

var $myTextbox = $('#ID_of_textbox');
var userNameIsContained = $myTextbox.val().toLowerCase().indexOf(userName) >= 0;
```

Short explanation:

```
$('#ID_of_textbox')  // fetches the jQuery object corresponding to your textbox
.val()               // the jQuery function that gets the textbox value
.toLowerCase()       // self explanatory
.indexOf()           // returns the position of a string in a string (or -1)
```

See the [JavaScript String object reference at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp).

Alternative (to check if the textbox value *equals* the username):

```
var userNameIsEqual = $myTextbox.val().toLowerCase() == userName;
```

Comment: will that check to see if it CONTAINS the username or IS the username? the text field will have other text in it... i want to make sure that the username is inside the entire string...

Comment: This will check if the textbox value *is* the username. I'll post an alternative to check if it *contains* the username.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to remember is that ASP.NET renames all your control ID's.  To access your controls in JavaScript, you should use the following in place of the Control ID <%= txtUserName.ClientID %>.

In jQuery, here is what my selector would look like for a textbox with the ID "txtUserName".

$('#<%= txtUserName.ClientID %>')

Enjoy,

Zach

Answer (score 0):

The basics of JQuery are like so:  Find a list of dom elements, and perform actions on them.

In your case, you should start off by finding the dom element that is your testbox.  For example's sake, we'll choose $('#userName').  The selector # means "id" and together with the name "userName" it finds all elements with the id of "userName".  (Ids on a page should be unique if you're following best practices.)

Once you have that list (in this case, a list of one element), you can ask it what the value is.
$('#userName').val()

This gets you the value of the value="" attribute of the input tag.

You can then assign it to a variable and use standard javascript String functions to do the rest!

Comment: that's part of the problem i guess... i don't really know standard javascript string functions :\

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkLogin(userName){
    return $('#mytextbox').val().toLowerCase() == userName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#textBoxID").val()) != "") { /*Do stuff*/ }
```